# Google Sheet data to json

Tags: go, google-apps-script

I've the below sample data at Google Sheets, is there a way to combine both Google Apps Script with Go Lang, so that I can work the sheet data as Json in my GO app?

[image]

Comment: App Script is not required.  Fetch https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/ID/values/RANGE where ID is the identifier of the sheet and RANGE is a range.  See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get.

Comment: @blunder Thanks, but this approach assuming I'm knowing the exact range, which may not be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

1- At Google drive, create new script sheet and write a code as below:

```js
function doGet(){
  // Open Google Sheet using ID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eLDCzOGyctqXgQmC5qULZ4thcNKsIOdKLJoYc762CTk");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  // Read all data rows from Google Sheet
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  // Converts data rows in json format
  const result = JSON.stringify(values.map(([a,b]) => ({ProductId: a,ProductName:b,})));
  // Returns Result
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Publish the script, youu may be asked for authintiction the first time you publish it, so you need to accept them (note: every time you make changes, you have to publish it under another version number)

[image]

set access to Anyone, even anonymous. and deploy.

[image]

Sign in with your google account. Go with unsafe options below.

[image]

Allow permission to get the URL of your web-app API.

[image]

2- In Go Lang, write the below code, using the link generated from the publish step before:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Product struct {
    ProductId   uint   `json:"ProductId"`
    ProductName string `json:"ProductName"`
}

func main() {
    // Read the returned response
    url := "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=WBSJPDNSN6X1FCYeXsR6TDaDval0vdvmSoMmXFhGbt5sfK0ia80Dp7kPD27GLpZbYz8vrwfDiUecI2oGMjEtgfL5o8Da25T1m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnGb6k9xaGtOX6M1tIiG811CRpk9nXl8ZKS7UJTno1dvQXMe1kqfAj8WxsSkLor-EqzOmbnRGq-tk&lib=M0B6GXYh0EOYMkP7qr1Xy9xw8GuJxFqGH"
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read the body of the response
    htmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // print out
    fmt.Println(string(htmlData)) // The data is returned as []byte, so string required to display it correctly

    // Unmarshall the returned []byte into json
    var products []Product
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(htmlData), &products)
    fmt.Printf("id: %v, description: %s", products[0].ProductId, products[0].ProductName)
}
```

Run the script above, you'll get:

```sh
PS D:\> go run gsheet.go
[{"ProductId":1,"ProductName":"Helmet"},{"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Glove"},{"ProductId":3,"ProductName":"Detecttor"}]
id: 1, description: Helmet
```

Notes:

In the go code, you need to ensure the below:
1- The unmarshal target struct must match the data
2- The fields types should be matching, for example `ProductID` should be `uint` it will fail if defined as `string`
3- The json OP got in output should match the tags used, for example, using `json:"id"` instead of `json:"ProductId"` for `ProductId` will fail